Why does using a conditional type fix the type incompatibility error?
I'm experiencing a type incompatibility error in TypeScript when using a generic type. However, using a conditional type seems to fix the issue, and I don't fully understand why. Here are the details:
I have defined a type IfAny and a generic type Box as follows:
type IfAny<T> = T extends any ? true : false;

type Box<T> = {
    value: IfAny<T>;
};

declare let a: Box<number>;
declare let b: Box<string>;
a = b; // Type 'Box<string>' is not assignable to type 'Box<number>'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)

As you can see, I get an error when trying to assign b to a, even though both Box<number> and Box<string> have the same structure where value is always true.
However, if I modify the Box type definition to use a conditional type, the error disappears:
type Box<T> = T extends any ? {
    value: IfAny<T>;
} : never;

declare let a: Box<number>;
declare let b: Box<string>;
a = b; // No error

Additionally, when I use type aliases, there is no error:
type A = Box<number>;
type B = Box<string>;
declare let aa: A;
declare let bb: B;
aa = bb; // No error

Playground
Why does using a conditional type or type alias resolve the type incompatibility error?
How does this behavior relate to TypeScript's handling of generic types and type compatibility?

In the type alias example both aa and bb has the value undefined and therefore the same type (also undefined). I think this is type narrowing? Where typescript understands what the actual (rather than theoretical) type is and act accordingly?

No, a declare means TS doesn't think they're undefined, it means they come from an external place.

The error is caused by a bug in TypeScript having to do with variance measurement (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) in conditional types, such as described in microsoft/TypeScript#31295.  See that issue and linked/related issues (like microsoft/TypeScript#31251 or microsoft/TypeScript#44945) for more information.

TypeScript's type system is structural, meaning that two types could be compatible even if they have unrelated definitions; type compatibility is determined by the shape of the type, not the name.  So when comparing two arbitrary types A and B, the compiler might have to do a bunch of work to fully evaluate both types, and then compare their structures.  This can be slow.
But when TypeScript compares two types of the form F<A> and F<B>, where F<T> is some type function, it can sometimes save work and time, by using the variance of F<T> with respect to its type parameter T.  If, for example, F<T> is covariant in T, then to check if F<A> extends F<B>, it can merely check if A extends B.  Or if F<T> is contravariant in T, then it can merely check if B extends A. Or if F<T> is invariant in T, then it can check if both A extends B and B extends A. Or if F<T> is bivariant in T, then it can check if either A extends B or B extends A. Oh, and if F<T> is independent of T, then it doesn't need to check A or B at all.
Of course an arbitrary type function might not have any simple relationship with its type parameter, in which case the variance is unmeasurable or unreliable (there is a difference between these I won't get into here), and the compiler might have to give up and fully evaluate F<A> and F<B> and compare them using the slower structural comparison, since neither A extends B nor B extends A is guaranteed to be relevant.

When variance measurements are used, TypeScript can speed up its type checking a lot, and arrive at the same answer as the slower structural check. That's the idea, anyway.
But sometimes TypeScript measures the variance incorrectly. It makes some simplifying assumption and decides that F<T> is, say, bivariant in T, but it isn't, truly. So then the same question, "is F<string> assignable to F<number>" might have apparently different answers depending on how the type checker evaluates it.  Since neither string extends number nor number extends string, then a variance-driven check will say that F<string> is not assignable to F<number>.  But if it turns out that F<string> and F<number>, when evaluated fully, yield equivalent types, then a structure-driven check will say that it is assignable. Oops.
And that's more or less what's happening here with Box<T>. TypeScript seems to have erroneously decided that Box<T> is bivariant in T, where in reality it's closer to independent.  When you compare Box<string> to Box<number> directly, it will erroneously decide they're incompatible. When you rewrite your type or the checks in a form that causes the compiler to evaluate them separately before comparing them, it will correctly decide they're compatible. It's a bug in TypeScript.

So then why don't they fix it? If you look at GitHub for issues about variance measurement, it turns out to be tricky to solve easily. The "obvious" fix is to just decide that, when in doubt, the variance is unmeasurable, and all checks should just fall back to structural checks. But this harms performance, sometimes disastrously so (see this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#56069). Any correctness improvement needs to be balanced against usability, so if the incorrect variance marker is close enough to correct enough of the time, it might be left in place. Here it sure looks like Box<T> should be almost independent of T, and that fix might not be too bad? But how often do people write type functions which independent of their type parameters? Why is T even present in Box<T> or IfAny<T> if it is almost always going to result in {value: true} or true? The cure might still be worse than the disease.
It's possible that a fix to microsoft/TypeScript#31295 might come someday, and if so, then your code will start working. Or maybe it won't, and you'll just have to be careful or work around it... or file an issue specifically for this example, but you'd likely need to argue based on some actual use case.
